# What does "pilgrim" mean in this paragraph?

Tags: word-meaning

I was reading this paragraph, and I saw this word and I don't know what does it mean. The story is about a girl whom lost her leg in an accident with a "horse Pilgrim". I can discern that it spouse to be someone fall from back of a horse or something like that, but what "Pilgrim" means here? And why it begins with capital letter?

Comment: In future questions, please tell us where  you found your paragraphs. See our [_Details, please_ meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) for more information about that.

Comment: I understand, but believe it or not, it was just one paragraph on a sheet of paper. nothing more. probably that was the reason I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Mike90: Even that is useful information. You can always tell us, “I don’t know where this quote comes from; it was just a single paragraph on a sheet of paper.” Every little bit of contextual information helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are reading *The Horse Whisperer* by Nicholas Evans.

*Pilgrim* is the *name* of the horse. This is why it is capitalised, and why you are reading about her "horse, Pilgrim".